# Write to Google Cloud Storage via Spark submit job (scala)

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, google-cloud-storage, hadoop-yarn

There are other posts that describes how to set configuration (spark and hadoop) for spark class to be able to write to GCS bucket.

If I run the below code from IntelliJ

```
package com.test.migration;

import java.io.File
import java.util

import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SaveMode, SparkSession}
object DFToGCSLite {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder
      .master("local[*]")
      .appName("DFToGCSLite")
      .config("spark.hadoop.google.cloud.auth.service.account.enable", true)
      .config("spark.hadoop.google.cloud.auth.service.account.json.keyfile", "src/main/resources/test-storage-318320-d3aa6f895415.json")
      .getOrCreate()

    import spark.implicits._


    val sc = spark.sparkContext
    sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.defaultFS", "gs://test-csv-write/")
    
      (0 to 100)
      .toDF
      .write
      .mode(SaveMode.Append)
      .parquet("outputs01")
  }
}
```

it writes to my GCS bucket perfectly.

But when I compile the jar and run it on a cluster like:

```
/usr/local/bin/spark-submit --class com.test.migration.CSVToGCS --master local /Users/adam.mac/Desktop/csv_to_gcs/target/scala-2.11/CSVToGCS-assembly-0.0.1.jar
```

changing `master.("local[*]")` to `master.("yarn")`

Also key file location is on a shared mount

it fails with

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemException: No FileSystem for scheme "gs"
```

built.sbt:

```
name := "CSVToGCS"

version := "0.0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

val sparkVersion = "2.4.0"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.1",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-yarn" % "2.4.0" % "provided",
  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-common" % "2.7.3",
  "com.google.cloud.bigdataoss" % "gcs-connector" % "hadoop3-2.0.0"
)
```

I have tried to set these config too:

```
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.gs.impl", "com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem")
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.AbstractFileSystem.gs.impl", "com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFS")
```

But I get the same result. I feel my configuration is incorrect somewhere, but how does the code work when I run just the class file from IntelliJ?

Comment: could you check if your jar is assembled properly? `jar tvf CSVToGCS-assembly-0.0.1.jar | grep gcs` ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved the error with the help of discussion on this github issue https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/hadoop-connectors/issues/323#issuecomment-597353458. Since we are using hadoop version 2.6, we were required to use this `gcs-connector-hadoop2-2.0.1.jar` available [here](https://storage.googleapis.com/hadoop-lib/gcs/gcs-connector-hadoop2-2.0.1.jar)

Once I placed the jar in $SPARK_HOME/jars/ the code worked just fine!